# Div with background-image overlayed by another div with background-image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to place 2 div elements containing background-image on the top of each other using the z-index property, but I'm struggling to make this work.

Ideally, I would like the `div banner-image` element to sort of slide underneath the `div banner-image-overlay` element as the screen is going smaller.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bocwmpsh/73/)

HTML:

```
<div id="banner-container">
  <div class="banner-image-overlay"></div>
  <div class="banner-image"></div>
  <div class="banner-text">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <button class="banner-button" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'">
    Button
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner-container {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}    
.banner-image {
  height: 375px;  
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/502x375');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}    
.banner-image-overlay {
  height: 375px;  
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/399x375');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  z-index: 99;
}    
.banner-text {
  max-width: 240px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Light', arial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 199;
}
.banner-button {
  max-width: 240px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Light', arial;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

I just can't figure out how to position them on the top of each other.

I've already had this working with the regular `img` tag and then using the `position: absolute` property, but this doesn't seem to work with the `background-image: url`

Any ideas?

Comment: The text element `<div class="banner-text">` is positioned correctly and seems to work just fine with the z-index

Comment: see these examples: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_halfpage_demo.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `position: absolute` for `z-index` work.

I have a better solution by using flex box:

```css
.banner{position:relative; display:flex;width:375px;height:500px; background:left top url(https://picsum.photos/300/300) no-repeat}
.banner-bg{flex:1 1;background:right top url(https://picsum.photos/200/280) no-repeat}
.banner-title{font-size:30px}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
   <div class="banner-bg">
       <div style="position:absolute;width:150px;right:10px;top:100px">
         <div class="banner-title">HERE IS LONG TEXT...</div>
         <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you see right background is placed above left background.

Answer (score 0):

div elements by default are positioned relatively which means they will be next to each other. z-index will not change their positioning. If you want to stack them you'll have to change their positions. Positioning one of them absolutely with left and top set to 0 will stack them.
add `position:absolute` to .banner-image-overlay.